# Tableau Personal Space 401 on Web Edit

Tags: tableau-api

We recently upgraded to the latest version of Tableau and are encountering a serious problem. No-one in the tableau community has answered the question and even our paid Tableau support is not responding to us!

We are embedding a viz in our site and then allowing users to click on the "Edit" button which opens up a web-edit version of the workbook. We have special permissions setup that allows them to even save their changes. This has all been working fine.

As of the most recent upgrades where Tableau introduced this idea of a Personal Space we now get a 401 when trying to save in the Web Edit (now labelled "Publish as")
Clicking "Publish As" loads a modal which is meant to display a list of locations to save to but instead displays a spinner which never goes away. The console indicates an error specifically wit the new personal space - 401 - No authentication credentials were provided.

We are using trusted ticket authentication to display our embedded vizzes and have had no problems with web edit saving until now. If we log directly into Tableau the web edit saves perfectly. So it seems to be an issue of Web Edit Saving + Trusted authentication, specifically as it relates to personal spaces.

Seems clear to me that this is a Tableau bug but wondering if anyone can suggest any kind of fix or workaround.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Determined that it works if the user authenticating happens to be the owner of the workbook. But still for other users (even though they have full permissions on the workbook) the "Publish As.." fails with a 401

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been confirmed by Tableau as a bug in their latest versions. Unclear when it will be fixed.
They provided us with the following workaround (which is not ideal from a security perspective) but works.

---

Workaround provided by Tableau. Configuration change required, setting unrestricted tickets to true.
https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/login-prompt-when-embedding-server
This is a temporary measure while Tableau develops a more permanent solution.